# Звідки взялося в українській мові слово мацьонька?

Tags: етимологія

У Дзідзя дуже популярним було використання слова мацьонька, знайшла також пісню ["Мацьонька"](https://www.cheremhi.com.ua/text/slova.php?id=3570) Мельниковича. Звідки воно взялося в українській мові? Це діалектизм чи, можливо, запозичення з якоїсь іноземної мови? У [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/macjonjka) таке слово взагалі не згадується.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одразу гадав, що те відоме мені і споріднене з південословʼянсим [*мачка*](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0) (*мацур*, відси і подальні чергування) — *кіт*, відси *кішення*. Оскільки українська дозволяє вживати назвами природи до людей (в пісні *малинка*, ба, навіть *пиво*) особливо до коханих, отже і тварин (туди ж *голубчику*).

Однак, це звичаєве *крихітка*: [*маценький*](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) — що відоміше як *маленький*. Хоч [декілька](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom3.pdf#page=421) словʼянських мов, як московська *мацупенький*, навіть українська — багато ріжновидів, до прикладу — *масінький*, булґарська *мацко* «мало» та півдесловʼянська *мацукан* мають подібного слова, са́ме слово *маценький* і похідні, ввважають, утворене під впливом польського *maciuci* через *ц*, хоч там читається ак *мачючі*.

Так маємо діялектізм, утворений під впливом чужослова.